# how to use two instance id of foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, e-commerce

I have four models of the shop, customer, product, an order.
I am showing the relation of models

### shop

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='shop', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, default='shop', )
address = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
Shop_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, )
```

### customer

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='customer')
Phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

### product

```
shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
Brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

### order

```
shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.CASCADE, null=True)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.CASCADE, null=True)
quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

when customers login then the shop will print on the screen and a button on shop to show the products by the shop in the form card. On the product card, there is an order button that adds the product in order after submitting the selected product will print with the remaining filled of order[image: That show in the mage] that shown in the image

how I create order form show that I get the id of shop and product

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the id of shop and product then you can create order in this way

```
def your_view_function(request,shop_id,product_id):
    customer = request.user.customer
    shop = Shop.objects.get(id=shop_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    # assuming you are getting value of quantity and note
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    note = request.POST.get('note')
    # or you are getting quantity and note from form
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer,shop=shop,product=product,quantity=quantity,note=note)
```

Comment: how to create URL

Comment: `path('your_url_text'/<int:shop_id>/<int:product_id>',views.your_view_function,name="url_name"`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options

Comment: I am getting an error Reverse for 'CreateOrder' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['CreateOrder/(?P<shop_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Please give me template for this

Comment: how use two id in html

Comment: I have use  product id   `<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info  shadow-lg" href="{% url 'CreateOrder ' i.id %}">`  and shop id is **i.shop.id** but how I can add into **href**

Comment: href="{% url 'CreateOrder ' i.id i.shop.id %}"

Comment: how I create input for **quantity** and **note**

Comment: Review django forms